# Is it allowed to use HeadlessUI and NuxtLabs UI together on Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, headless-ui

Just a beginner question here for nuxt developers, Is it allowed to use [HeadlessUI](https://headlessui.com/vue) together with [NuxtLabsUI](https://nuxt.com/modules/nuxtlabs-ui) on Nuxt 3 Project? Since these two ui libraries are based on tailwindcss framework.

Answer (score 2):

The link to NuxtLabsUi you provided is a Nuxt 3 Module, so the integration is very easy, you just need to follow two usual steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://ui.nuxtlabs.com/getting-started/installation):

1. Run

```
npm install --save-dev @nuxthq/ui
```

or the equivalent yarn command

2. Add the module to your `nuxt.config` file as follows:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@nuxthq/ui',
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
})
```

You are now ready to go.
From what I read on your link, Nuxtlabs-Ui is powered by Headless UI.